# Django crontab, running a job every 12 hours

Tags: django, python-3.x, cron

I have a django crontab sceduled to run every 12 hours, meaning it should run twice per day however, it is running more than that.
Can anyone tell me what's wront with it ?

```
('* */12 * * *', 'some_method','>>'+os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'log/mail.log'))
```

Also what changes I need to make if I need it to run every 24 hours?

Comment: Your expression is wrong, it should be `0 */12 * * *`, because you want it to run once and not "every minute". For every 24 hours just change 12 to 24.

Answer (score 2):

After every 12 hours you want to run job any particular minute from 0 to 59, not every other minute. So it should be (assuming `0th` minute):

```
('0 */12 * * *', 'some_method','>>'+os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'log/mail.log'))
```

For once in a day or every 24 hours (You can decide any specific hour from 0 to 23, assuming at midnight):

```
('0 0 * * *', 'some_method','>>'+os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'log/mail.log'))
```